# Leaving a handler on img.onload is a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, html, memory-leaks

Is it correct that this code causes a memory leak in the browser?

```
/**
 * @param {Canvas2DRenderingContext} ctx
 * @param {string} url
 */
function loadImageDrawIntoCanvas(ctx, x, y, url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  }
  img.src = url;
};
```

My understanding is that because img is a DOM element and because I'm attaching JavaScript to it with `img.onload` the browser will never garbage collect this. To correct that I'd need to clear `img.onload` as in

```
/**
 * @param {Canvas2DRenderingContext} ctx
 * @param {string} url
 */
function loadImageDrawIntoCanvas(ctx, x, y, url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    img.onload = null;          // detach the javascript from the Image
    img = null;                 // needed also so the closure doesn't keep
                                // a reference to the Image?
  }
  img.src = url;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be a leak, as long as it's implemented correctly by the browser.

Old versions of Internet Explorer (7 and earler) had a GC that couldn't deal with circular references between JS and DOM nodes. There are a lot of guides out there that suggest clearing event listeners before removing DOM nodes because of this, and jQuery does this automatically. (NB: Other browsers might have had fautly GCs at some point, but old IE is the famous one.)

The interesting part here is that the GC needs to know if `onload` will be fired again in the future or not.

I just tried rendering 275 MB of images to a canvas using code similar to what you posted, and Chrome does not leak. (By comparison, if I store the images in an array outside of the loop, then 275 MB are retained.) Firefox might leak [some?], but it's hard to tell because its memory overhead is much higher than Chrome's.

Why?

- On the javascript-side, `onload` and `loadImageDrawIntoCanvas` both complete execution and no remaining references to the `img` remain.
- On the browser implementation-side, they've done something functionally equivalent to incrementing the reference count on `img` when you call `img.src=`, and decrementing it once `onload` is fired. Chrome has two tests for these sorts of leaks ([1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/testing/data/listener/listener_leak1.html), [2](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/testing/data/listener/listener_leak2.html)).